# Is there a way to alter the design without creating table from scratch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm creating a database in SQL Server Management Studio which contains some tables plus stored procedures, now I have set all relationship between all tables but I want to alter something in the design of some tables however it keeps telling me the changing you have made require the following table to be dropped and re-created.

Is the a way do alter the design without creating table from scratch ??

Comment: What are you trying to change exactly?

Comment: I want to change the identity specification .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off **this option here** (under the `Tools > Options` menu in SSMS) and you'll be able to make your changes:

[image]

It's checked (and thus activated) by default after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can often issue an ALTER TABLE statement against the database even when SQL Management Studio believes that table recreation is required.